# Query creation method gives error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

My Entity has a field like

```
@Column(name = "workflow_status", columnDefinition = "nvarchar(255)")
private String workflow_status;
```

So in my Controller I want to fetch the entries by `workflow_status`, I wrote the Query method that JPA provides

```
List<Programme> findByWorkflow_status(String workflow_status);
```

But this gives error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query method public abstract java.util.List com.taap.backend.programmes.repositories.ProgRepo.findByWorkflow_status(java.lang.String)! No property workflow found for type Programme!
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:207) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:451) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:224) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property workflow found for type Programme!
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:247) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:398) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:378) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:89) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:70) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
... 58 common frames omitted
```

Any help is highly appreciated! :)

Comment: rename your property to follow java conventions and the stuff might work `private String workflowStatus`

Comment: thanks for that. Completely forgot the convention.

Comment: Please share your method which select Programme by workFlowStatus. I think you have syntax error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Underscore(_) character in spring JPA has reserved meaning.

- Either, change the name of the variable, which is highly recommended.

Change

```
private String workflow_status;
```

to

```
private String workflowStatus;
```

and

```
List<Programme> findByWorkflow_status(String workflow_status);
```

to

```
List<Programme> findByWorkflowStatus(String workflow_status);
```

- Or, escape the character by using another underscore.

Something like this:

```
List<Programme> findByWorkflow__status(String workflow_status);
```

For more information refer the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/).

Comment: Another question, can we use these Query methods to fetch a single column's data instead of the entire row/s? Is something like `findNameById(Integer id)` where `name` and `id` are Entity variables?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to do this directly. You can use @Query annotation, something like this: `@Query("select name from programme where id = :id")
Integer findNameById(Integer id);` See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) for more.